# How to get SubtleCrypto work with testcafe?

Tags: javascript, cryptography, e2e-testing, testcafe

I am generating SHA256 using [SubtleCrypt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto/digest) Web API on client-side as following:

```
const hashBuffer = await crypto.subtle.digest('SHA-256', msgBuffer);
```

Everything works fine except for when I execute tests via **`testcafe`**. The captured console error says `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'digest')` meaning `crypto.subtle` is undefined.
I know that `SubtleCrypto` is available only in [secure contexts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Secure_Contexts) which also includes `localhost` and I am using `localhost` to run my end-to-end testcafe tests.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to run TestCafe over HTTPS protocol. See more information in the following help topic: [test-https-websites](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402839/guides/advanced-guides/test-https-features-and-http2-websites?search#test-https-websites).